# Two symmetric dice painted different colours

Tags: probability

Two symmetric dice have both had two of their sides
painted red, two painted black, one painted yellow.
and the other painted white. When this pair of dice is
rolled, what is the probability that both dice land
with the same colour face up?

I haven’t worked this out yet, but is the process simply counting the number of outcomes as two regular dice getting the same number (1/36 chance) but with 4 possibilities instead?

Comment: Yes, but the possibilities for color do not have equal probability like the six faces of standard dice.

Answer (score 1):

$\underbrace{\left( \frac{1}{3} \right)^2}_{red} + \underbrace{\left( \frac{1}{3} \right)^2}_{black} + \underbrace{\left( \frac{1}{6} \right)^2}_{yellow} + \underbrace{\left( \frac{1}{6} \right)^2}_{white} = \frac{5}{18}.$